# Reading only first character of each line in file

Tags: c, file

I'm currently trying to read and process only first character in each line of a ".c" file. So far i have came to this code, but n is not even printed ot od the loop:

```
void FileProcess(char* FilePath)
{
    char mystring [100];
    FILE* pFile;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    char c;
    int n =0;
    pFile = fopen (FilePath , "r");
    do {
      c = fgetc (pFile);
      if (isupper(c)) n++;

    } while (c != EOF);

    printf("6");
    printf(n);
    fclose (pFile);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `printf("%d\n", n);` ?  (the compiler should have warned you about your current code btw)

Comment: That loop doesn't read the first character of each line, it read *every* character in the file. You might want to use e.g. `fgets` to read a line into a buffer, and then get the first character from that buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

1. You are not printing n correctly. You are feeding it to `printf` as the "formatting string". It is surprising that you get away with it - this would normally cause havoc.
2. You are reading one character at a time. If you want to print only the first character of each line, better read a line at a time, then print the first character. Use `fgets` to read entire line into a buffer (make sure your buffer is big enough).

Example (updated with inputs from @chux - and instrumented with some additional code to aid in debugging the "n=1" problem):

```
void FileProcess(char* FilePath)
{
    char mystring [1000];
    FILE* pFile;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    char c;
    int n =0;
    pFile = fopen (FilePath , "r");
    printf("First non-space characters encountered:\n")
    while(fgets( myString, 1000, pFile) != NULL)
      int jj = -1;
      while(++jj < strlen(myString)) {
        if ((c = myString[jj]) != ' ') break;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
      if (isupper(c)) {
         printf("*U*\n"); // print *U* to show character recognized as uppercase
         n++;
      }
      else {
         printf("*L*\n"); // print *L* to show character was recognized as not uppercase
      }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("n is %d\n", n);
    fclose (pFile);
}
```

**NOTE** there are other more robust methods of reading lines to make sure you have everything (my favorite is `getline()` but it is not available for all compilers) . If you are sure your code lines are not very long, this will work (maybe make the buffer a bit bigger than 100 characters though)

Comment: On point 2,  reading 1 `char` at a time and testing for a `\n` (and printing the next char) is a solution that is not limited to the buffer length of `fgets()`.

Comment: Minor ideas, not to really take away from your answer: 1) `fgets( myString, 100, pFile) != NULL)` is more portable and idiomatic (NULL is not always 0) and I'm not certain all valid pointers are positive.  2) I find `fgets(myString, sizeof myString, pFile)` easier to maintain.

Comment: @chux - you are right, I was confusing syntax of `fgets()` and `fscanf`. The latter returns EOF (-1), 0 (no arguments matched), or >0 (number of arguments matched). I will update.

Comment: with the code above i get that "n is 0" but there are upper characters in the file im reading.What do i do ?

Comment: Are these uppercase characters in the leftmost column ("first character of each line") or further down? Maybe you meant "first non-space character"?

Comment: yes i meant first non=space character. How do i manage to do that ?

Comment: @AlexanderDemerdzhiev I have made an edit to address your problem - did not have a chance to test. Let me know if this works. I only test for "space" (`' '`); it would be possible to test for "whitespace"  (includes tab) by using `if(!isspace(c = myString[jj])) break;`

Comment: Well "n" counts ot one with this check.I think gets doesnt get on the next line but im not sure.

Comment: @AlexanderDemerdzhiev I have made some edits to the code to help you debug this. I hope they make sense. Remove the `printf` statements once you figured out what is going on - and tell me what you discover.

Comment: Well it works fine with normal text, thank you very much! Now i need to do some modifications so it works wit text formated like a code from c program so i have to exclude some symbols like # and { and }.
If i have some futher questions, would you be that kind to help me ? :)

Comment: Glad this works. If this answers your question, would you be kind enough to accept it (with the check mark). Then post a new question for follow-up. You can add a link as a comment here (and a link from the new question to this old one) so help people see the context of the new question.